# What is the difference between super().__repr__() and repr(super())?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, super, repr

In python (3.5.2), I was expecting the `repr(obj)` function to call the magic method `__repr__()` of `obj`'s class. 
However calling both of them do not seem to yield the same result. Can anyone explain why ?

Sample code :

```
class parent:

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = "haha"

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.a)

class child(parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.b="bebe"

    def __repr__(self):
        return "("+super().__repr__()+", "+repr(super())+", "+self.b+")"

    def print1(self):
        print("super().__repr__() returns:", super().__repr__())
        print("repr(super()) returns:", repr(super()))
        print("plom(super()).__repr__() returns:", plom(super()).__repr__())
        print("repr(plom(super())) returns:", repr(plom(super())))

def plom(var):
    return var

t=child()
print(t.__repr__())
print(repr(t))
print('-----')
t.print1()
print('-----')
print(plom(t).__repr__())
print(repr(plom(t)))
```

result :

```
>>> 
 RESTART: test super.py 
('haha', <super: <class 'child'>, <child object>>, bebe)
('haha', <super: <class 'child'>, <child object>>, bebe)
-----
super().__repr__() returns: 'haha'
repr(super()) returns: <super: <class 'child'>, <child object>>
plom(super()).__repr__() returns: 'haha'
repr(plom(super())) returns: <super: <class 'child'>, <child object>>
-----
('haha', <super: <class 'child'>, <child object>>, bebe)
('haha', <super: <class 'child'>, <child object>>, bebe)
>>>
```

Comment: Because `super` returns a proxy object, not the class itself.

Comment: How can I get the superclass from my object itself from it, then ? and why does it work with `__repr__()` ? In what way is `repr` different from `__repr__` ?

Answer (score 9):

Calling `repr(super())` directly accesses the `__repr__` on the `super` *class* (technically, the `tp_repr` of the C `PyTypeObject` struct defining the `super` type). Most special dunder methods behave this way when called implicitly (as opposed to explicitly calling them as methods). `repr(x)` isn't equivalent to `x.__repr__()`. You can think of `repr` as being defined as:

```
def repr(obj):
    return type(obj).__repr__(obj)  # Call unbound function of class with instance as arg
```

while you were expecting it to be:

```
def repr(obj):
    return obj.__repr__()  # Call bound method of instance
```

This behavior is intentional; one, customizing dunder methods per-instance makes little sense, and two, prohibiting it allows for much more efficient code at the C level (it has much faster ways of doing what the illustrative methods above do).

By contrast, `super().__repr__()` looks up the method on the `super` *instance*, and `super` defines a custom `tp_getattro` (roughly equivalent to defining a custom `__getattribute__` method), which means lookups on the instance are intercepted before they find the `tp_repr`/`__repr__` of the class, and instead are dispatched through the custom attribute getter (which performs the superclass delegation).

Answer (score 2):

If you consult [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super), you'll see that `super` returns a proxy object which delegates method calls to the appropriate class according to method resolution order.

So `repr(super())` gets you the representation of the proxy object. Whereas the method call `super().__repr__()` gives you the representation defined by the next class in the method resolution order.

If you want the superclass itself, try

```
my_object.__mro__[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

In `super().__repr__()` you're calling the repr class of the super object so you get `'haha'`

In the second, you're calling repr of the `super()`. what does `super()` output? `<super: <class 'child'>, <child object>>` so you're effectively calling repr on some class hierarchy

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me : Why would super() output something different between super().__repr__() and repr(super()) ?

Comment: I added some cases and I don't understand why `super()` would make that difference when my `plom(t)` function doesn't. Isn't super a regular function ?